# Trying to combine For and If loop

Tags: matlab, if-statement, for-loop, math, octave

I watched a video on the 3n + 1 conjecture and just wanted to try and see if I could create a simple program to replicate a few cycles of it.

What I would like to do is make it so that the program takes an input number, decides if it's odd or even. If even divide it by 2 and then use that number to continue the loop. Or if the value is odd multiply it by 3 and add 1 and then continue the loop.

i.e if the number was 7, it's odd so go to 22, that's even so go to 11, that's odd so go to 34, that's even so go to 17 and so on.

Here's my attempt at it, I just wanted to try it for fun and got nowhere. I'm hoping it's just something small I have to do with the code, if not I can leave it.

```
#Want to do 10 loops of n
#If n is even /2
#if n is odd n*3 +1
n = input("enter first value for n")
for i = (n:10); 
  disp(i)
  if mod(i, 2) == 0
  % i is even
  ans = sprintf("%d", i ," is even")
  newn = (i/2)
  disp(ans)
  else
  % i is odd
  ans = sprintf("%d", i ," is odd")
  disp(ans)
  newn = (3*n +1)
  end
end
```

EDIT:

I had issues replying with code so here is the updated code I got help with that seems to work well. I don't know why the sprintf wasn't working too well.

```
n = input("enter first value for n")
for i = 1:10 
  if mod(n, 2) == 0
  % n is even
  n = n/2
  else
  % n is odd
  n = 3*n +1
  end
end
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: You mix between `i` and `n`, and have no use for `newn`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
clc

n = input('Enter first value for n : ');

number_of_loops = 10;

for i = 1 : number_of_loops
    disp(['Loop # ', num2str(i)]);
    if mod(n, 2) == 0
        disp([num2str(n), ' is even']);
        n = n/2;
    else
        disp([num2str(n), ' is odd']);
        n = 3*n + 1;
    end
    disp(['New number = ', num2str(n)]);
end
```

Comment: Thank you Prakhar. That works great. I didn't know about num2str.

Comment: You could also add a check for n == 1 before ending the for loop and break out of it. It can tell you how many iterations it takes before reaching 1 for the first time. Something like: `if n == 1 disp(['Reached 1 in ', num2str(i), ' iterations']); break; end`

Comment: @JamesBlackwell Prakhar is presumably to shy to say so, but if this answers your question correctly then please spread some good mojo all around by accepting it as an answer (by clicking on the tick mark) and also consider upvoting it.

Comment: My apologies, I'm new to the website! I have now done both :)

Comment: Haha! Thanks Tasos and James!

Answer (score 0):

There were several issues with your code, including but not limited to variables that were being calculated but never used, and a strange mix of `i` and `n`.

Not sure if this is perfect, but I think this should be roughly what you wanted to do:

```
#Want to do 10 loops of n
#If n is even /2
#if n is odd n*3 +1
n = 123
for i = (1:10)
  disp(i)
  disp(n)
  if mod(n, 2) == 0
  % n is even
    disp(sprintf("%d%s", n ," is even"))
    n = (n/2);
  else
    % n is odd
    disp(sprintf("%d%s", n ," is odd"))
    n = (3*n +1);
  end
end
```

Comment: had issues posting code. Will try again with another answer

Comment: @JamesBlackwell That is pretty much what I suggested. Note that for sprintf you had 2 inputarguments that you both tried to print as decimal (with strange results). In this answer it is shown how you could have called it.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you for your help with this Dennis. I have lots to learn